# NestJS : transform responses

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

With NestJS, we can transform incoming request `@Body()` using the validation pipe.

Similarly I would like my responses transformed using https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer `classToPlain`.

This is so that I can map field values to the response format, example:

```
export class FoobarDto {

    @Transform((money: ExchangeableMoney) => money.localValues)
    public foobar: ExchangeableMoney;

}
```

What is the idiomatic way to achieve this in NestJS?

Comment: Maybe you can use Interceptors. https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Typically you would use the built-in [`ClassSerializerInterceptor`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization) in combination with the `ValidationPipe` (with `transform: true`). It automatically calls `classToPlain` on the response:

In your dto (with `toPlainOnly`):

```
@Transform((money: ExchangeableMoney) => money.localValues, {toPlainOnly: true})
public foobar: ExchangeableMoney;
```

In your controller:

```
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
```

or [globally](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#binding-interceptors) in your main.ts:

```
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector)));
```

Comment: Hello @Kim Kern. Is there a way to turn on the ClassSerializerInterceptor globally, just as we can with the ValidationPipe?

Comment: Hi @JasperBlues! You can enable any pipe globally with the `useGlobalPipes` method in your `main.ts` file. See https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#class-validator for an example

Comment: Awesome, great answer, Kim Kern! And thank you  @FWoelffel for the comment.

Comment: import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
/* Why not use Reflector directly */
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(Reflector));

Comment: Is there a way to refactor the `Transform` decorator to a function of some sorts so we can reuse a transformer somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

An update to this answer, if you've updated to the latest version of 'class-transformer' package.

```
@Transform(({ value }) => value.localMoney)
public foobar: ExchangeableMoney;
```